# Changing Memcache serializer

Tags: php, serialization, memcached, igbinary

I want to change the default Memcache serializer (`Memcached::SERIALIZER_PHP`) by replacing it by Igbinary (`Memcached::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY`) in a server that already contains caches.

If I make the change, I think that the Memcache server will attempt to unserialize the old caches with Igbinary and, therefore, it will crash.

Is that assumption correct? Is it necessary to perform a `flush_all` action in order to avoid errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but flush_all will mark all entries invalid by setting the experation date to now. If this is acceptable for you, it's probably a solution.

Comment: I want to change the serializer and I don't know if it is **absolutely necessary** to perform a `flush_all`

Comment: It think there is no option to do this "on the fly". But you certainly can update (deserialize (old way) / serialize (new way)) every entry by script. In case you can accept rebuilding your caches, flush_all is less sophisticated.

Comment: @marfis I prefer invalidate all caches because it's much easier and I can assume it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. If you changethe Memcached serializer all existing entries are incompatible. You will need to perfom a `flush_all` to start fresh as you mentionned.